# How to save a tkinter photoimage in folder?

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library

Trying to save the image in my specified directory but it is displaying error that type is not str

```py
image.save()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, we can't answer your question if you don't give us enough information. Please [edit] your question to include a complete, [mre], along with the _full error traceback_, so that we can debug the problem. Read [ask] for more information on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to save an image to a file, from a `tk.PhotoImage`.

### Solution

`save()` is not a method of PhotoImage class. You will have to use `write()` instead.

> **PhotoImage.write** Write image to file FILENAME in FORMAT starting from position FROM_COORDS. [*Read here*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d985c8e2e0d38e6905cc27124008eb926254247b/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L4149)

### Example

```py
# try not to import globally
import tkinter as tk

ws = tk.Tk()

a = tk.PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
a.write('sample.png')

ws.mainloop()
```